# Dynamic XML parsing, data storage, and forms in c#

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, dynamic, data-storage

So I am developing an application that I want to be able to dynamically parse an xml file, grab attributes and populate a form that is created based on what elements are present in the xml file. Then the values can be edited, and written back to the xml file that was originally opened.

I've been able to parse, save values to a database , populate forms, and write back to the original xml file via hard coding, and I think I have an idea for the dynamic "database" structure (a dictionary where the key is a node's name, and the value is a dictionary if I wanna store a node's child node information, or a string if I'm in the furthest nested child node of an element).

I'm stuck on how to grab the information I need and how to store it in the "database" structure I've come up with. I've done research and have seen people use the "dynamic" object and linq. But everything I've seen seems to involve knowing the path names they've needed before run time. Any ideas on how I should be going about actually parsing the file and grabbing data, first off? I think if I can get that figured out, the rest should kind of fall into place.

Say I have this xml

`<users>
  <user1 age="43">John Doe</user1>
  <user2 age="40">Jane Doe</user2>
</users>`

An example database setup would look like `Dictionary<users, Dictionary<user1, Dictionary<name,John Doe>`

Where you could go `Key("users").Key("user1").Key("name").Value` to get John Doe or something like that.

Any other suggestions for my database setup would also be appreciated

Comment: I would look into xml serialization. It's the easiest and most efficient way to go about xml parsing in my mind. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58a18dwa%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Why do you have separate tag definitions (user1 and user2) for what looks like the same element? If you need to specify user IDs `<user id="1" age="43">John Doe</user>` would be more idiomatic.

Comment: I think I did it because I have the tag name as the key somewhere down the embedded dictionary line, and there's more than one user, so my key names wouldn't be unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could parse xml using **XmlDocument** class. After parsing you have tree of nodes which you can traverse and show in UI. I don't understand why you want to save xml as distinct records of values in database, just save it as text. Anyway for saving xml you should translate its records back to xml.

Comment: So I used the **XmlDocument** method to parse my files, which worked great. Now I wanted to use dictionaries to store my data because I want to be able to group controls on a form based on data that have the same parent node. I got it to work for files that don't have leaf nodes with the same name. But it needs to work for both. What would be an efficient way to store the data preserving this "grouping" by parent element?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you are looking for is XML serialization. Before you can do that though, you need to simplify your xml. Instead of numbering the `<user>` elements, you will want to use an attribute that has the value for the user id. For example you can use an `id` attribute.

```
<users>
  <user id="1" age="43">John Doe</user>
  <user id="2" age="40">Jane Doe</user>
</users>
```

Once you have done this, create a class that you can serialize to this xml.

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "users")]
public class Users : List<User>
{

}

[XmlType(TypeName = "user")]
public class User
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "age")]
    public int Age { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then all you have to do to load from the file is deserialize.

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Users));
Users users = (Users)serializer.Deserialize(File.OpenRead("XMLFile1.xml"));
```

You can use LINQ to query the `Users` collection for specific users.

```
var user1 = users.Where(u => u.Id == 1)
```

Modify the `User` objects or add more to the `Users` collection, then serialize to save changes back to the file.

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Users));
serializer.Serialize(File.OpenWrite("XMLFile1.xml"), users);
```

Comment: Looks good for the file I gave as an example, but I need it to be able to read in an xml without knowing what kind of data is in the xml at compile time. Wouldn't this only work for a static application that only reads in a file with the "users.xml" format?

Comment: Yes this would only work for the one format. In order to process the file you have to know something about the format at compile time. What will you know? Also is it possible to come up with a single format that can capture all the info you need? If this is an option it may be better than having a bunch of parsing & persisting code.

Comment: I only know that there's a root node with children. That's it.